# JFugue Duration map string-millisecond based on BPM

Tags: jfugue

Is there a way to get millisecond duration of a jfugue duration like w, given a specific BPM rate?

Something like:

```
int millisDuration = durationManager.getMillis("w", 120);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the closest thing is a method in `NoteSubparser` called `getDurationForString("UPPERCASE STRING")`, which will return a double that represents the portion of a whole note that the string is. For example, passing `"H"` for a half-note will return 0.5. The string can be arbitrarily complex, such as `"WWWH."` (three whole notes and a dotted half), which will return 3.75. Since the value returned is relative to beats, and you have a BPM in mind, you should be able to calculate the milliseconds from that.

Use `NoteSubparser.getInstance()` to get an instance of NoteSubparser, then call `getDurationForString("W")` (Edit: It's necessary to use capital letters when calling parser code directly like this).

Comment: Hello David :) Thanks for your library and your quick follow up! I am a big fan! double millis = noteSubparser.getDurationForString("w"); --> Is retrieving 0.25. Am i missing something here?

Comment: First, getDurationForString returns a value relative to beats, not millis. But also, I would expect 'w' to return 1.0, and I'm wondering if there's a calculation that is assuming 4 whole notes makes a beat. I'll look into this.

Comment: Try using capital W. When using JFugue, the code converts the string to uppercase before processing it, but when calling a method directly like this, there is no uppercasing happening inside the code. I should fix this. (With the lowercase 'w', a case statement is falling through to the default condition, which is a quarter note)

Comment: Very nice! With capital letter works perfectly! Thanks again!